# Render latex text from within r function in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, hmisc

I am working within RStudio 1.1.383 using rmarkdown. I am trying to render to Latex a string that is created within a knitr chunk so that it appears as latex code within the document.

So far I have experimented with the 'results=' options in the chunk header and find that results='asis' enables it to be rendered once the document is knitted, but I have not been able to find a way to enable the result to be rendered using the preview feature that allows you to run a single chunk and see the results within the .Rmd editor.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

A minimal example is included below that should be copied into a .Rmd file before rendering.

Thanks in advance,

Michael

````
---
title: "Minimal Example"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
str <- "$$\\alpha \\cdot \\beta = \\delta$$"

# this doesn't show in the preview 'run chunk feature'
cat(str, "\n")

# neither does this
writeLines(str)
```
````

Comment: shouldn't you set `str` with `cat(str,"\n")`?
I mean `str<-cat(str,"\n")`

Comment: `results='asis' `

Comment: Thank you both results='asis' works when the document is rendered. In RStudio 1.1.383, , Latex can be inputted in .Rmd documents between dollars  i.e $$  \LaTeX code $$ and it will render immediately as a preview. The preview still does not work with this method, however the final result works so I am happy with that.

Anyone know if there is a way to get the rendered text to show in the notebook preview feature of .Rmd documents in RStudio 1.1.383?